# What does shuf -e means in bash

Tags: bash, shell, shuf

I have string save as

```
test="test1 test2
test3 test4
test5 test6"
```

and

```
echo $(shuf -e $test)
```

it gives me the same output as $test, why? I expect the different order of the original string

Comment: `shuf (GNU coreutils) 8.28` shuffles the words for me in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. What linux distro and version are you running.?

Comment: I run it on git bash not working, but works on the terminal rh8

Comment: I'm glad that you found a way to make it work :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm.

```
$ test="test1 test2
> test3 test4
> test5 test6"
$ echo $test
test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6
$ echo $(shuf -e $test)
test4 test5 test2 test6 test1 test3
$ echo $(shuf -e $test)
test5 test2 test4 test3 test6 test1
```

Maybe by chance it just happened that the "randomly" chosen permutation for you was the identity permutation? Did you try several times?

Comment: Thank you, it works now